# Is using vi to view log files in PROD servers not recommended?

Tags: server, vi

We have Ubuntu servers in production. Our lead architect tells me we should not use VI to view log files. Instead use `cat`.

I want to know if there is any inherent risk associated with using vi/vim to view log files.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with using `vi` (or `vim`) as a viewer only, if you are disciplined enough not to accidentally write to the file.

If you accidentally write to a log file you may lose any new log file entries made since you opened it (although vim may in some cases warn you of this).  You may also lose data due to confusion when the log file rotates.  Log file rotation is a process where the old logfile's filename is automatically changed (or deleted, or compressed) and a new logfile is started.

- An alternative to `vim` that is *only* a viewer (cannot edit) is **`less`** - and it has vim-like controls too for scrolling and searching.  I find it a good program for viewing log files, or lists in general such as lengthy output of commands, because of its vim-like controls and search ability.
- Another good alternative is **`tail`** because it allows you to view just the last portion of the file, and has a follow mode which can stay active and display additional content as it's added to the log file.  It's also aware of log rotation so it can keep displaying new entries after a log file rotation.  To use the rotation-aware follow mode you use `tail -F mylogfile.log` and you can stop it with just Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

Vi is a powerful editor when used by an experienced user, but it is not inconceivable that a novice user might accidentally delete or otherwise modify the log file.  It might be that your architect is afraid of this happening.

Having said that, a user should not have write permission on most log files anyway.  My guess is that your architect thinks that commands like `less`, `cat`, `more` are simply more expedient than starting a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Going along with the other good answers, perhaps more in keeping with the intent of "using vim" that was asked in the question:

Trying using **`view`**

This symlink just starts vim in read-only mode and is available by default in Ubuntu for as long as I remember.

Comment: AFAIR this is identical to `vim -R`.